# Spark - Dependency between partial calculations / columns

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

We are currently migrating an old .NET solution of a huge calculation, into to Spark (Databricks), as the current solution does not scale near well enough for our needs.

The main result of the calculation is based on many partial calculations.

Until now, it has working great by using `.withColumn`; appending the results of the partial calculation, based on some of the data already available.

But now I am stuch with a new scenario.

The scenario goes like this;

- `Calculation A` is dependent on yesterdays result of `Calculation C`.
- `Calculation C` is dependent on `Calculation B` (for the same day)
- `Calculation B` is dependent on `Calculation A` (for the same day)
- `Calculation A` is dependent on yesterdays result of `Calculation C`.
- etc...

  - The dependencies goes on until Day "0", where `Calculation C` will have the initial value of 0.
- Note that neither  the result of `Calculation B` or `Calculation C` exists yet, so I do not see how I can make use of the lag functionality.

As I understand; loops are a no-go in Spark, especially with larger datasets.

How would I manage such dependencies i Spark?

## Example

`Calculation A`: Prev. day result of `Calculation C` + 123

`Calculation B`: Current day result of `Calculation A` + 2

`Calculation C`: Current day result of `Calculation B` - 4

Day 1:

- `Calculation A` result: 123 (0 + 123)
- `Calculation B` result: 0 (prev. day does not exist; initial value)
- `Calculation C` result: 0 (prev. day does not exist; initial value)

Day 2:

- `Calculation A` result: 123 (0 + 123)
- `Calculation B` result: 125 (123 + 2)
- `Calculation C` result: 121 (125 -4)

Day 3:

- `Calculation A` result: 244 (121 + 123)
- `Calculation B` result: 125 (123 + 2)
- `Calculation C` result: 121 (125 - 4)

Day 4:

- `Calculation A` result: 244 (121 + 123)
- `Calculation B` result: 246 (244 + 2)
- `Calculation C` result: 242 (226 - 4)

Day 4:

- `Calculation A` result: 365 (242 + 123)
- `Calculation B` result: 246 (244 + 2)
- `Calculation C` result: 242 (246 - 4)

etc...

Comment: Sounds like something you might do with a lag/offset window function, but its hard to help without an actual example of expected input/output

Comment: I'll try to add a example. Again, the scenario above is very simplified, as we are talking about a huge chain of partial calculations that needs the yesterdays result from each other.